# IntelliJ: How to autocomple AND import statically Collectors.toList()

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-stream

When I program in Java in IntelliJ, I often use streams and collect them to list:

```
list.stream()
  .whatever()
  .whatever2()
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

IntelliJ has a nice feature that I can just type '.toL' and the autocomplete generates the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` for me.

[image: Intellij]

How can I change the settings so the Collectors.toList is automatically imported statically?

```
list.stream()
  .whatever()
  .whatever2()
  .collect(toList())
```

Edit: I know how to statically import any method, but I want autocomplete do this in one step.

Comment: The link above shows how to do this manually, but OP wants it to be done automatically. This is not duplicate question.

Comment: I think this is handled by [Smart completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#smart_completion), but it doesn't seem possible to customize it. I notice however that it will use the `static import` if it is already present.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

1. After you have written your code, place your cursor on "Collectors" and press alt + enter and choose the highlighted option below.

[image]

[image]